# What is the difference between two codes ? why is there time complexity different?

Tags: python, data-structures

code snippet 1 -

```py
def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: bool
    """
    num2=[]
    for x in nums:
        if (x in num2):
            return True
        num2.append(x)
    return False
```

while running the code, the compiler shows TLE on leetcode but I think the time complexity of the above code is O(n) as it is iterating once through the list

code snippet 1 -

```py
def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: bool
    """
    num2=set()
    for x in nums:
        if (x in num2):
            return True
        num2.add(x)
    return False
```

The above code is accepted.

But I don't understand why, there's no difference except that `num2` is a set. Please suggest some possible explanations.

Comment: What is the time complexity of membership tests in sets? What about in lists?

Comment: Also note the second snippet won't work. Sets have a `.add`, not a `.append`

Comment: "it shows TLE" - What is "it"? And no, `in [list of elements]` and `for _ in list` is iterating two lists. Therefore O(N*M), not linear time

Comment: I think TLE is the time limit exceeded, OP might have shared a competitive coding question.

Answer (score 1):

As for the 1st snippet, just because you have used only 1 loop, makes it O(n), the inner operation `if x in num2` which uses another `n` utilizing linear search, making it overall quadratically time complex or `O(n^2)`.

Whereas for the 2nd snippet, `if x in num2` for `set` works differently as searching any element in sets uses a constant or O(1) time, making the overall process linearly time complex or `O(n)`.

This was for time complexity.

Your 2nd snippet is incorrect, as `sets` don't have an `append` function, they instead use the `add` function for that functionality.

Comment: No, `set` implements a hashtable, a hashtable lookup is amortized O(1), there are some small operations done at each lookup to make future lookups faster, that aren't part of the lookup itself. The cost of a single lookup is spread to multiple lookups, and the constant time is only average case, the worst case is O(n).